# Java - Need a logging package that will log the stacktrace

Tags: java, logging

Is there a Logger that will easily log my stacktrace (what I get with
`ex.printStackTrace()`)? I've searched the log4j docs and found nothing
about logging the stacktrace.

I can do this myself with

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
ex.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
String stacktrace = sw.toString();
logger.error(stacktrace);
```

but I don't want to duplicate this code all over the place.

If log4j won't do this for me is there another logging package that will
log the stacktrace for me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Using [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html#error%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Throwable%29) this is done with:

```
logger.error("An error occurred", exception);
```

The first argument is a message to be displayed, the second is the exception (throwable) whose stacktrace is logged.

Another option is [commons-logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/guide.html), where it's the same:

```
log.error("Message", exception);
```

With [`java.util.logging`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html) this can be done via:

```
logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Message", exception);
```

Comment: Any standard facility to just log the stacktrace? Sometimes I just don't know (or want) what to put in the message

Answer (score 3):

In [java.util.logging](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html) you can initialize the logger with custom log formatter like here:

```
private Logger initTextLogger() throws SecurityException, IOException {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(YourClass.class.getName());
        FileHandler fileHandler = new FileHandler(logFilePath, false);
        SimpleFormatter logFormatter = new SimpleFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String format(LogRecord record) {
            String stacktrace = "";
            Throwable t = record.getThrown();
            if(t!=null){
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                t.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
                stacktrace = sw.toString();
            }               
            return record.getLevel() + ": " + record.getMessage() + "\r\n"
                    + stacktrace;
        }
        };
        fileHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter);
        logger.addHandler(fileHandler);

        return logger;
    }
```