# When to log a stacktrace for a caught exception

Tags: java, logging, exception

I recently asked [whether to report the `getMessage()` text of a caught exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320080/should-you-report-the-message-text-of-exceptions). Rather surprisingly, most answers misunderstood my question and thought I was asking whether to report the stack-trace for a caught exception, suggesting that doing so is considered the norm. So I'm asking a follow up question.

In which circumstances should you, or should you not, report a stack-trace when you `catch` an exception? By "reporting" I include [asking a logging framework to log the stack-trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332095/java-need-a-logging-package-that-will-log-the-stacktrace/2332110#2332110) for you.

I am not asking whether to report *something*. I'm asking whether that report should include the stack-trace.

Answer (score 9):

I personally try to obey these rules:

- if I can handle the exception in the catch in a 'recoverable' way (e.g. a DateFormatException), no need to trace the stack
- if I want to rethrow the exception, log no stack trace. (rethrow in a chained way to retain this information)
- if I handle the exception in a catch block as an error case (e.g. sql error), I log the stack trace.
- if it's a runtime exception, I would suggest the framework (yours or whatever you use) does the tracing.

Comment: "an error case": could you clarify what you consider an error case?

Comment: "a runtime exception": you mean an exception of class `RuntimeException`; that is, an un-checked exception?

Comment: "an error case": anything unexpected, but that is hard to interpret. For instance, an optimistic locking exception can be sth expected (that is, you handle it and show an error) or unexpected (it should never happen, fatal error, show stack trace), depending on the situation.

"a runtime exception": exactly, as you suspected

I would add one rule: when in doubt, trace the stack.

Answer (score 3):

It's context dependent.  For example, I might not log / report a ParseException from NumberFormat when parsing input from an external system, but I would definitely do so if I caught a ParseException which was dealing with data enclosed within the boundary of my system, since this would indicate an inconsistency in internal system state rather than an input value validation falure.

Comment: "an inconsistency in internal system state" = an indication of a bug.

Answer (score 3):

**You** - the developer - will need the stack trace if you are in an error situation.  Hence you need some way of getting it out of the JVM and on to you.

If you do not log it to a file then what will you do?  Files are the most reliable thing available in a JVM so you should at least put it there before sending it on the network.

Comment: "in an error situation": could you clarify what you would consider an "error situation". Only when catching an un-checked exception?

Comment: @Raedwald, in a situation where the exception was not expected.  mcfinnigan mentioned ParserExceptions - you most likely do not want to log those (unless they happen in unexpected places).

Comment: So, you do not mean exceptions of class `Error` (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html).

Comment: @Raedwald, no, in a situation where the exception was unanticipated by the code.  When unanticipated you need all the help you can get to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

A stack-trace is useful to a programmer who wants to debug a bug indicated by the exception. It is not useful to anyone else, for which the method names and call sequence are meaningless, and the verbosity is a distraction. Therefore, you should log a stacktrace **if, and only if, and always if, the exception indicates a bug** in the program. However, that does not always indicate that a method you write should `catch` and log the exception. In practice, bugs are indicated by unchecked exceptions, so it is easier (and often better) to let the exception be thrown from the method, and handled at a higher level: if you are using a framework, it will probably log the exception for you (often with additional useful information); the JVM itself will probably log any exception thrown from `main`.

Answer (score 0):

I usually report exceptions not related to GUI. GUI Exceptions are common, and in heavy Swing programs usually happens.

Generally speaking, i'm deeply interested in: DB related exceptions, My-own-stupid-errors exceptions (array out of bounds, and stuff like that) and some other things that cannot be handled by me, like WebServices etc.

I think it depends the type of system, if it's a public one (like a website), or if it's private (intranet sites, GUI local)

Comment: "My-own-stupid-errors exceptions": you mean un-checked exceptions?

Comment: It depends the way you're reporting your exceptions. If you're doing it in your try-catch block, then unchecked exceptions would be difficult to log. But, you can have more high level exceptions similar, like asigning a negative integer to an Employee ID, and you might want to rise an exception.

Answer (score -1):

I would report all of them. But if you are using log4j then you can control which ones you know for sure you will not be interested to see in the log. If a particular user exception has a different class, then disable logging in that class in production and enable it in lower environments. In that way, you are not doing anything at the code level for reporting. Its all abstracted at the logging framework.

Comment: "you are not doing anything at the code level for reporting": that defers the decision from programming-time to configuration-time, but the question still remains: for which do you report a stack-trace?

Comment: I generally log an exception right within the constructor of an exception. In that case, I dont need to log anything explicitly. The minute I instantiate an exception it gets logged. Hence I was saying, if you dont want to report a particular exception make sure that disable it in the log4j properties. For the original question, I think definitely you would want to report all exceptions in dev and then disable most of them in prod.

Comment: "The minute I instantiate an exception it gets logged": that is against whole point of exceptions, which is to separate the detection and initiation of error handling (the throw part) from completion of handling and reporting (the catch part).