# Show SQL Exception by Error Code range

Tags: java, oracle, error-handling

I'm trying to iterate through a SQLException Object and to filter the Error Code for each of his index.

```
public static void showExceptionByErrorCodeRange(SQLException ex, int range_min, int range_max){
    String msg = new String();
    int error_code = 0;
    Iterator<Throwable> itr = ex.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        SQLException e = (SQLException)itr.next();
        error_code = e.getErrorCode();
        if(error_code >= range_min && error_code <= range_max){
           msg += e.getMessage();
        }
    }
    showErrorMsg(msg);
}
```

This code compile, but it looks like the SQLException has only one index because the *while(itr.hasNext())* only loop once and the *e.getMessage()* returns this:

```
ORA-20000: The vendor-specific error message i need to select by my function.\n
ORA-06512: at "any_table", line x\n #<-- default SQL error message.
ORA-06512: at line 1\n #<-- default SQL error message.
```

I'm able to get the *e.getErrorCode()* to 20000, but when i add the *e.getMessage()* to my *msg* i get all the errors in the same string. (ORA-06512)

Is there any way to seperate the errors (ORA-20000 and ORA-06512) from the *getMessage()* string without using string logic?

Thank you.

Comment: This heavily depends on the implementation of the driver from the database vendor. Looks like for this case, you won't be able to do it.

Comment: you might try http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause() on the chance that Oracle's driver chains the exceptions that way instead of the SQLException specific http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#setNextException(java.sql.SQLException).

Comment: Possible duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954166/java-what-information-in-error-stack-trace-do-we-typically-not-wish-to-show-use

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: what information in error stack trace do we typically not wish to show users?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954166/java-what-information-in-error-stack-trace-do-we-typically-not-wish-to-show-use)