# printStackTrace to java.util.logging.Logger

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java.util.logging, throwable, printstacktrace

How do I print the entire stack trace **using** java.util.Logger?  (without annoying Netbeans).

*The question should've originally specified staying **within** Java SE.  Omitting that requirment was an error on my part.*

```
-do-compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/rainmaker/build/empty
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/rainmaker/build/generated-sources/ap-source-output
    [javac] Compiling 13 source files to /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/rainmaker/build/classes
    [javac] /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/rainmaker/src/model/TelnetEventProcessor.java:44: error: 'void' type not allowed here
    [javac]                 log.severe(npe.printStackTrace(System.out));
    [javac]                                               ^
    [javac] 1 error

BUILD FAILED
```

code with the error:

```
package model;

import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TelnetEventProcessor extends Observable {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TelnetEventProcessor.class.getName());
    private String string = null;

    public TelnetEventProcessor() {
    }

    private void stripAnsiColors() {
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\e\\[[0-9;]*m");
        Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(string);
        string = regexMatcher.replaceAll(""); // *3 ??
    }

    public void parse(String string) {
        this.string = string;
        ifs();
    }

    //       [\w]+(?=\.) 
    private void ifs() {
        log.fine("checking..");
        if (string.contains("confusing the hell out of")) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\w]+(?=\\.)");  //(\w+)\.
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
            String enemy = null;
            GameData data = null;
            while (matcher.find()) {
                enemy = matcher.group();
            }
            try {
                data = new GameData.Builder().enemy(enemy).build();
                log.fine("new data object\t\t" + data.getEnemy());
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers(data);
            } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                log.severe(npe.printStackTrace(System.out));
            }

        } else if (string.contains("Enter 3-letter city code:")) {
            log.fine("found enter city code");
        } else {
        }
    }
}
```

see also:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7100975/262852

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The `severe` method is only used to log severe messages without associated throwable information. If you need to log throwable information then you should use the [`log`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#log-java.util.logging.Level-java.lang.String-java.lang.Throwable-) method instead:

```
try {
     data = new GameData.Builder().enemy(enemy).build();
     log.fine("new data object\t\t" + data.getEnemy());
     setChanged();
     notifyObservers(data);
} catch (NullPointerException npe) {
     log.log(Level.SEVERE, npe.getMessage(), npe);
}
```

Comment: the only problem with this answer is that it's rather verbose -- but that's Java for you!

Comment: This is the first time that I see someone catching a NP exception!

Answer (score 12):

Why don't you put the exception in the logger?

You can use this method :

```
logger.log(Level level, String msg, Throwable thrown)
```

Comment: I think this is the simplest way to achieve the desired result.  Will have to try it, of course.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe a duplicated question? [Java - Need a logging package that will log the stacktrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332095/java-need-a-logging-package-that-will-log-the-stacktrace)

Below the explanation from the given url

> Using log4j
>   this is done with:
>
> ```
> logger.error("An error occurred", exception);
> ```
>
> The first argument is a message to be displayed, the second is the
>   exception (throwable) whose stacktrace is logged.
>
> Another option is commons-logging,
>   where it's the same:
>
> ```
> log.error("Message", exception);
> ```
>
> With `java.util.logging`
>   this can be done via:
>
> ```
> logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Message", exception);
> ```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You don't explicitly print the stack trace; `Throwable`s have stack traces attached to them, and you can pass a `Throwable` to the log methods:

```
log(Level level, String msg, Throwable thrown)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use Apache ExceptionUtils. In your case

```
try {
     data = new GameData.Builder().enemy(enemy).build();
     log.fine("new data object\t\t" + data.getEnemy());
     setChanged();
     notifyObservers(data);
 } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
     logger.info(**ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(npe)**);
 }
```

Comment: Your solution helped me. Another workaround:  `logger.severe(Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));`

Answer (score 3):

You should redirect the System.err to the logger, the process is not too simple but you can use this code:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class LogOutputStream extends ByteArrayOutputStream {//java.io.OutputStream {

    private String  lineSeparator;
    private Logger  logger;
    private Level   level;

    public LogOutputStream(Logger logger, Level level) {
        super();
        this.logger = logger;
        this.level = level;
        this.lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() throws IOException {

        String record;
        synchronized (this) {
            super.flush();
            record = this.toString();
            super.reset();

            if ((record.length() == 0) || record.equals(this.lineSeparator)) {
                // avoid empty records 
                return;
            }

            this.logger.logp(this.level, "", "", record);
        }
    }
}
```

And The code to set this (that should called the when you first create the logger

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Exception");
LogOutputStream los = new LogOutputStream(logger, Level.SEVERE);
System.setErr(new PrintStream(los, true));
```

This will redirect the System.err stream to the logger.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try to use [ExceptionUtils from apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/exception/ExceptionUtils.html#getStackTrace%28java.lang.Throwable%29)

Answer (score 1):

The exception is due to the [`printstacktrace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29) method being `void`, meaning it doesn't return anything. You are trying to do:

`log.severe(npe.printStackTrace(System.out));`

My guess is that the `severe` method needs a `String` and not `void`.